# Correct filepath to read from file

Tags: c#

I want to read from a file. But i do not how to alter to the correct filepath.

I just want to read from a file called Level.txt. If I do; `string path = "Level.txt"`.
 The program tries to search it from; `C:\...\ProjIV\ProjIV\bin\x86\debug\Level.txt`.
 When I want the damn thing in: `C:\...\ProjIV\ProjIV\ProjIVContent\Level.txt`.

Skip the second question. As someone else said, one question at the time. Also; solved.

Comment: Instead of describing your program, **show your code**. Describe in more detail what the specific problem is. Compile error? Runtime Exception? Unexpected behavior? We can't tell you what's wrong with the code if we can't see it. Also, one question at a time.

Comment: You could do string path = "../../Level.txt";

Comment: about the second part,by any chance you reffering to rectangular arrays?

Comment: What about using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`? It should work to get the program's base directory `C:\...\ProjIV\ProjIV`, and then you could just add `ProjIVContent\Level.txt` to the end of it, as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just provide a path like that, your program will search in the running (working) directory that it is executing in. You can provide an explicit path:

```
C:\<whatever you need here>\ProjIV\ProjIV\ProjIVContent\Level.txt
```

Or a relative path:

```
..\..\..\..\ProjIVContent\Level.txt
```

That's pretty ugly though, I'd stick with the first one. Or move `Level.txt` into your working directory.

Comment: Instead of moving level, you should set Visual Studio to copy it during compilation.  Otherwise you may loose your file

Comment: @Andrey That is indeed another option, though I don't see why the file would be lost.

Comment: Thank you. Although for anyone who reads this in the future.  flip the \ to / to avoid making \\ all the time.

Comment: @tnw I am pretty sure with some setting Visual Studio clears the build folders.  Also if you don't set it up correctly it will not come along when you do your release build, or package your installer.  Overall copying anything into the compilation folder is asking for trouble